# Japanese Manga, Kid Main character

Tags: story-identification, manga, isekai

Basically a male mc isekais to a world of non-magic, but he discovers there isn't any magic out there so he is disappointed big time. So his next step is to invent magic of sorts, and one of the manga chapters is using two ores to create lightning/static magic while in a blacksmith..... I think?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is *[Magic Maker: How to Create Magic in Another World (Magic Maker: Isekai Mahou no Tsukurikata)](https://myanimelist.net/manga/157056/Magic_Maker__Isekai_Mahou_no_Tsukurikata)*

> A man who was thirty years old and wanted to use magic died
> unexpectedly, and when he woke up, he was reborn in another world.
> Named Theon, he had high hopes that there would be magic in another
> world, but there was no magic in that world.
>
> Theon became depressed and lethargic, but an event led him to discover
> the existence of magic.
>
> "That's right. If there is no magic, then I will make it myself."
>
> With this in mind, Theon began researching magic from that day
> onwards. Eventually, through the spread of a disease that can only be
> cured by magic, and a chance encounter with an enemy that can only be
> defeated by magic, Theon becomes a hero who saves the world. This is
> the story of a simple magic fool who, while tossed about by fate,
> overcomes it with the power of magic and an indomitable fighting
> spirit, ultimately propagating magic to the people.
>
> [image]

I found the answer on Reddit.